# Left turns at major intersections

Tags: pgrouting, routing, shortest-path

My pgRouting shortest path algorithm is able to take restrictions and oneway streets into account. Threrefore, OSM data was imported into a PostGIS database using the tool pypgroutingloader. Sadly, the left turn at major intersections is still not accurate. Using a different import-tool (like osm2pgrouting) does not help either.

This is, what a correct route (south to west) looks like (using OSRM).
[image: OSRM]

My setup currently generates the shortest path like this:
[image: pgRouting]

As you can see, it is not violating the oneway-rule. It illegaly turns left at the node after the driveway.
How could I get rid of that behaviour? I already thought about calculating the angle between segments and ristricting sharp turns... But I have no idea about how to do that.

Comment: I'm a beginner in Python.
I'm trying to install pypgrouting which is supposed to be a Python package but there's no setup.py.
How am I supposed to do then, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the turn restrictions into the dataset. MapBox have been working on this with the Openstreetmap data using the Turn restrictions plugin in JSOM - see [this blog post](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/turn-restrictions/) for more details or using the iD editor ([see here](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/simple-editing-for-turn-restrictions-in-openstreetmap/)).

Comment: As OSRM already uses the correct way it is highly likely the turn restrictions are already there. But no idea how to enable 'considering turn restrictions' for pgrouting ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It led me to the right direction :)

As I mentioned above, thanks to pypgroutingloader the restrictions ARE already in the database. I just had to use the pgr_trsp() function pgRouting is offering. I used the aStar function in the SQL query before where restrictions were not being considered. Now I am able to route correctly through the whole dataset.